# ¿Como puedo contar la cantidad de caracteres del atributo "contenido" en java?

Tags: java

```
package Libreria;


public class Pagina {
    //Atributos
    private int numero;
    private String contenido;
    //Constructores
    public Pagina(){
        numero=0;
        contenido="";

    }

    public Pagina(int numero, String contenido) {
        this.numero = numero;
        this.contenido = contenido;
    }
    //Propiedades

    public String getContenido() {
        return contenido;
    }

    public void setContenido(String contenido) {
        this.contenido = contenido;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    //Metodos

    public int obtenerCantidadCaracteres(){


    }
    public String obtenerDatos(){ 
        StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Cantidad de caracteres:             ").append(obtenerCantidadCaracteres()).append("\n");

         return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: Hola Kevin, podrias ser mas detallado en tu problema, que es lo que te falla exactamente, que errores te devuelve java.

Answer (score 2):

Sólo bastaría con hacer:

```
return contenido.length();
```

Lo que hace length() es retornar la cantidad de caracteres del objeto.

Puedes ver más info [aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_length.htm)